# Change ObservedObject Value with Wkwebview

Tags: swift, swiftui, wkwebview, combine

I am using `WkWebView` for my app. When the view is loaded I would like to display the score Natively and not in the `WkWebView`. I used the `combine` Frame work to create an `ObservableObject` in order to display my score to the view and other views when the score changes in the `WkWebview`. I use `window.onload` to get the most recent score and display it when the page first renders. I do so by calling a JS function which sends a message to the Native side `webkit.messageHandlers.bridge.postMessage("0")`  with the score and assign the sent score to my `ObservedObject`. The issue is on the Native side. The `UserContentController` function, which handles the message from the `WkWebview`, keeps printing out the score and reassigning the score to my `ObservedObject`.  It seems to be stuck in a loop. I provided a simplified version of the code below. Have been stuck on this for a few days now and cant seem to fix the issue.

```
 //Holds the score
class Myscore:ObservableObject{
@Published var score = "0"

}


 //Wkwebview
struct WebView: UIViewRepresentable {
@ObservedObject var myScore : Myscore

 class Coordinator: NSObject, WKNavigationDelegate, WKScriptMessageHandler {
    var webView: WKWebView?
    var myScore: Myscore
    init(myScore:Myscore) {
        self.myScore = myScore
        super.init()
        
    }
    
    
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        self.webView = webView
    }
    
    // receive message from wkwebview
    func userContentController(
        _ userContentController: WKUserContentController,
        didReceive message: WKScriptMessage
    ) {
        // This is where the issue occurs
        var newscore = message.body as! String
        myScore.score = newscore
        print(myScore.score)
    
    }
    
  }

func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
    return Coordinator(myScore:myScore)
}

func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
    let coordinator = makeCoordinator()
    let userContentController = WKUserContentController()
    userContentController.add(coordinator, name: "bridge")
    
    let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    configuration.userContentController = userContentController
    
    let _wkwebview = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: configuration)
    _wkwebview.navigationDelegate = coordinator
    
    return _wkwebview
}

  func updateUIView(_ webView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
    guard let path: String = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "index", ofType: "html") 
 else { return }
    let localHTMLUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: path, isDirectory: false)
    webView.loadFileURL(localHTMLUrl, allowingReadAccessTo: localHTMLUrl)
   }
 }

//Content View to display the Score
struct ContentView: View {
 @StateObject var myScore = Myscore()

var body: some View {
    VStack {
     
        Text("Your Score is\( myScore.score)")
        WebView(myScore: myScore)
    }
   }
  }
```

Edit here is the html side:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, viewport-fit=cover">
</head>
<body>
<button>click me</button>
<hr/>
<div id="log"></div>
<script>
    window.onload = function () {
        webkit.messageHandlers.bridge.postMessage("98 points")

    
    }
 
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Edit 2: This is what the console prints out
[image: This is what the console prints out]

Comment: I copied and pasted your code into a new iOS project.  Your sample doesn't show where you set up the "onload" handler so I added some code to load a static HTML string into the web view that included an onload handler that posted a new score.  That did not put the code into a loop for me.  The coordinator's message handler was only called once (with the new score).  Could the problem lie with code outside of what you have shown?

Comment: @ScottThompson could you show me the Html side. I'll my html. Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/70654606/12299030? Updating binding is the same as updated observed object property here.

Comment: @Asperi the problem happens with the window.onload. So when the doc is loaded I want it to automatically send the score so it shows up when the WkWebview shows. If I make a button and send the score when the button is pressed I have no issue. Just when using window.onload on the html side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here I see cycle loading by updating `Myscore` which result in `updateUIView` call and so forth...

Initial loading should be placed into `makeUIView`

```
func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
    let coordinator = makeCoordinator()
    let userContentController = WKUserContentController()
    userContentController.add(coordinator, name: "bridge")
    
    let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    configuration.userContentController = userContentController
    
    let _wkwebview = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: configuration)
    _wkwebview.navigationDelegate = coordinator

    // make here initial loading !!!
    guard let path: String = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "index", ofType: "html") 
 else { return _wkwebview }

    let localHTMLUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: path, isDirectory: false)
    _wkwebview.loadFileURL(localHTMLUrl, allowingReadAccessTo: localHTMLUrl)

    
    return _wkwebview
}

  func updateUIView(_ webView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
     // reload should be made here only if base url changed
     // externally
   }
```

Tested with Xcode 13.4 / iOS 15.5

Comment: That explains why I did not see the problem when I tried.  I was putting the HTML in to the web view in `makeUIView` instead of including a file to be loaded in `updateUIVew`

Comment: @Asperi Thank you so much for your help that worked! Btw if it's not too much to ask. Could you explain to me "Cycle Loading". And is this the proper way of loading the html in the makeUIView ? I saw some tutorial on Wkwebview and that is why i was loading in the UpdateUIView. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: You were loading your HTML `updateUIView`.  This caused the "onload" for the document to fire and change the state of you SwiftUI View.  When the state of a `UIViewRepresentable` changes, the system calls `updateUIView`.  This caused the "onload" for the document to fire and change the state of you SwiftUI View...  Now you're in a cycle where you load the content, it emits an event, that event causes you to load the content -- hence "Cycle Loading".  To break that cycle you only load content when the view is first created.

Answer (score 0):

`score` should be `@Binding` and `updateUIView` will be called automatically when it changes. Unfortunately this is one of the many undocumented magic behaviours of SwiftUI's structs.

FYI `ObservableObject` is designed to assign a Combine pipeline to an `@Published`. Try and stick to structs for your data and use `@State` and `@Binding` to make your value types have reference type semantics.