# how to communicate between WKWebView in swiftUI with javascript in HTML5

Tags: javascript, swiftui, wkwebview

I use WKWebView within swift UI， may I please ask how I can communicate between Javascript in Html5 and WebKit? I use userContentController, and also called userContentController.add(message handler, name: "message handler"), but I couldn't find the WebKit property in the window property in the Html5， it is undefined. I don't know how to adjust my code, and how to call the website to communicate with the WebKit to WKWebkit in Javascript, below is my code

```
 func updateUIView(_ uiView:WKWebView,context:Context) {
        if let url = url, let requestURL=URL(string:url){
            let webConfiguration=WKWebViewConfiguration()
            let userContentController=WKUserContentController()
            webConfiguration.userContentController=userContentController
            
            uiView.load(URLRequest(url:requestURL))
            var cache=URLCache.init()
            URLCache.shared.removeAllCachedResponses()
            URLCache.shared.diskCapacity=0
            URLCache.shared.memoryCapacity=0;            
            userContentController.add(messageHandler, name: "messageHandler")

        }
        
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/70654606/12299030?

Comment: I found my problem, I didn't add the configuration into the webview

Comment: Does the answer provided from the link solve your problem? if not, Can you @ivyyeziyang provide your solution, please? Thanks!!